# What OBD II protocol does the 2004 Ford Explorer use?

Tags: ford, obd-ii, explorer

Does the 2004 Explorer use J1850 or some other protocol?  Is there a way to extract codes by jumpering pins on the OBD connector?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It should be using PWM J1850 protocol as almost all Fords use that one. You can see if it's the PWM by looking at the DLC itself. You'll see the connector which looks like this:

[image]

It should have metallic contacts in pins 2, 4, 5, 10, and 16.

Since the advent of OBDII, almost no vehicle OBDII systems will allow you to jumper pins to get the codes. There are still a few out there, but I'm pretty sure Fords won't let you.

Comment: Thanks Paulster2.  Any idea how to retrieve codes without a scan tool?

Comment: If you are here in the States (probably Canada as well), you can go to many of the major parts chains (ie: AutoZone, Advance Auto Parts, etc.) and they will pull the codes for you for free.

Answer (score 1):

Save up your pennies and for 11 to 15 bucks you can order a scan tool with Bluetooth that will readout on your smart phone. I just bought one on amazon for less than 12 bucks made by Foseal works great on my 2005 Sportrac which uses PWM J1850 protocol. 
I bought a Chinese knockoff for 7 bucks but it would not talk the protocol...

Comment: Very true about the cheap ones - I had to spend *10 what you did for one that works.

Answer (score 0):

No, Ford like others switched from J1850 to CAN, OBDII protocol around 2003-2004 model years, some were a little later than others when the engine choice was an older engine.

Fortunately the cheap generic bluetooth and wifi scanners sold in various places are even more likely to read CAN than J1850.  Some claim they can read "all" OBDII but can't actually read J1850.

There is no way to jumper pins to read codes.  Buy a scan tool or get it done for free at an auto parts store offering this service, or for pay at a shop selling the service.